# TrafficStats functions always return -1

Tags: android, networking, statistics, traffic-measurement

When i try to retrieve traffic data using TrafficStats class,

`TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()` and `TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()` functions always return -1 even if i use the browser to load some web pages.

I knew from some forums that -1 mean that the device don't support the action. I used WVGA, NEXUS ONE and NEXUS S and the problem persists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using emulator it might not work. Try on a real device.