# Android monitoring network usage

Tags: android

I am having Android client and server both running in my local PC. My Client is an activity(project) in eclipse while my server is a jar file in the same PC. I use emulator as my client and I connect to the server using Wi-Fi or sometimes LAN. I configure my client with IP obtained by `ipconfig`, so it is local environment. (When connected over Wi-Fi, I use WLAN IP and for LAN, I use `eth0`).

I am monitoring the `rx`,`tx` data sent and received by the client. I am using this:

```
int uid = android.os.Process.myUid();
long tx=TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
long rx=TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid);
```

I am always getting this `rx` and `tx` values as `-1` each.

I am also using this piece of code:

```
String info = "";

            info += "Mobile Interface:\n";
            info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets() + " packets\n");
            info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets() + " packets\n");

            info += "All Network Interface:\n";
            info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");
            info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

            Log.d("hi", "Netwrk" + info);
```

I am getting `TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()` and `TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()` as `0` while `TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()` And `TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()` as `-1` each.

Why is that `-1` always? Is it because both client (emulator) and server are in same PC?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the answer. The value `-1` returned indicates `TrafficStats` is `UNSUPPORTED` in Emulator. Similar discussion in [TrafficStats functions always return -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330735/trafficstats-functions-always-return-1) also says the same.