# Not able to activate internet on android emulator...?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to activate internet on android emulator. I have tried all different methods but still not find way..... My office PC which I use has proxy setting which are as follow :

```
 IP : 10.1.2.23
 Password : admin123
```

I tried running my emulator using command line option as follow :

Attempt : 1

```
emulator.exe -avd MyAVD -no-audio -http-proxy http://puser1:admin123@10.1.2.23:8080
```

Attempt : 2 (Below DNS are configured in my PC)

```
emulator.exe -avd MyAVD -no-audio -http-proxy http://puser1:admin123@10.1.2.23:8080 -dns-server 10.1.14.25,10.1.14.26
```

Attempt : 3

I tried to resolved by follwing reference but not able to solve it.

http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html

[No internet on Android emulator - why and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)

[How to connect android emulator to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039964/how-to-connect-android-emulator-to-the-internet?lq=1)

[How to setup Android emulator proxy settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings)

Comment: did you turn on wifi in the virtual device?

Comment: I am not using WiFi, am using BroadBand

Comment: but in the device you need to turn on wifi to set up internet

Comment: WiFi or Mobile Internet....? Mobile Internet is on as its show white 3G symbol "3G!"

Comment: wifi turn on wifi for LAN with your host machine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330735/trafficstats-functions-always-return-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue myself. Posting what I have tried so that it helps others

I have proxy setting  as below :

```
IP : 10.1.2.23
Password : admin123
```

1) Run :

If you are starting android emulator from command line then try below command :

```
emulator.exe -avd MyAVD -no-audio -http-proxy http://puser1:admin123@10.1.2.23:8080 -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

If you are starting android emulator from eclipse then make sure you have added below setting :

```
Window --> Preferences --> Android --> Launch --> Default Emumator Options : -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Run --> Run Configurations --> Android Application Name --> Under Target Tab Select Emumator --> Additional Emumator Command Line Options : -no-audio -http-proxy http://puser1:admin123@10.1.2.23:8080
```

2) Add Proxy Setting in android Emumator :

```
Setting --> Wireless networks --> Celluler Network / Mobile Network --> Access Points Names --> Edit Default One (In my case --> T-Mobile US,epc.tmobile.com) and add proxy setting with username and password.
```

**Don't forget to save setting.**

Do not change or enter any others settings.

**3) If Still Internet is not active then try to turn on / off mobile internet 2 to 3 times.**

**4) If still Internet is not active then try to turn on / off Airplane Mode 2 / 3 times keeping mobile internet on.**

Comment: I had '@' in my password so it is make mistake when I use emulator.exe -avd MyAVD -no-audio -http-proxy http://puser1:admin@123@10.1.2.23:8080 like this so How can I over come it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to -> ***mobile network settings -> Access Point Names***
here you will find ***T-mobile US (APN)*** by default or add any new one, for now just click and add following fields:

```
Username: android
password: android
APN Protocol: ipv4
```

username and password can be anything I guess but I set it to android for simplicity.

this setup worked for me.

thanks